# how to get full url for file stored with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have three models: User, Article and Comment, each user has a profile picture.

I did the following query to select all comments with some user's attributes

```
article = Article.find(params[:id])
article.comments.joins(:user).select('comments.*, users.username, users.profile_file_name')
```

I have the profile_file_name but how do I get the full URL.

(If I had an user object I could just do user.profile.url)

Answer (score 0):

write something like this in your model.

```
has_attached_file :asset, :path => "/var/lib/project_name/snaps:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", :url=> "http://www.somedomain.com/snaps/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```